# Abstract class parameter in intermediary class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I'm trying to define an abstract class with a mandatory argument. It works fine, but if I add an intermediary class, it may raise an exception at some point. Here is a dummy code to replicate the issue:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Dict
 

class AbcClass(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def MAP(cls) -> Dict[str, str]:
        raise NotImplementedError
 
    @property
    def map(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return self.MAP
 
 
class InterClass(AbcClass):
    MAP = None  # NotImplementedError if not provided
 
    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return "text"


class ConcreteClass(InterClass):
    MAP = {
        "a": "b"
    }

 
c = ConcreteClass()
print(c.map)
```

With this implementation, everything's working well, but if I remove the line with the comment in the `InterClass` it raises an `NotImplementedError` exception. The point I don't understand is, I know the `MAP` parameter is mandatory, but as long as I define it in the `ConcreteClass`, why do I have to also implement it in the `InterClass` ?

Comment: Mixing `@classmethod` and `@property` is just a massive source of weird bugs. The whole design turned out to be a mistake, and the feature was removed in 3.11 because it caused so many more problems than it was worth.

Comment: It's interesting that this is the case. However if you have defined `InterClass` in such a way that it is not valid to instantiate it then it should also be an abstract base class

Comment: @user2357112 the design is actually the only way I've found to define an abstract class parameter, if you have another solution it is also more than welcome